# android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout failed to instantiate

Tags: android-layout, material-design

I am getting error while try to use TextInputLayout  in android

I have android support library version 23. but still getting error

my xml file showing error is

he following classes could not be instantiated:

```
- android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout (Open Class, Show Error Log)
See the Error Log (Window > Show View) for more details.


11-25 00:58:30.967: E/AndroidRuntime(27848): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.
11-25 00:58:30.967: E/AndroidRuntime(27848):    at android.support.design.widget.ThemeUtils.checkAppCompatTheme(ThemeUtils.java:34)
11-25 00:58:30.967: E/AndroidRuntime(27848):    at android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.<init>(TextInputLayout.java:103)
11-25 00:58:30.967: E/AndroidRuntime(27848):    at android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.<init>(TextInputLayout.java:96)
11-25 00:58:30.967: E/AndroidRuntime(27848):    ... 24 more


11-25 13:32:29.967: E/AndroidRuntime(18136): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.odibly.android-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.odibly.android-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

11-25 13:32:29.967: E/AndroidRuntime(18136):    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
```

Comment: have you added that library into your project?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to add the following to your module `build.gradle` file:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

And use **com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout** in your XML:

```
   <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/text_input_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/my_hint">
```

Comment: This is what worked. But why? one jar is included inside the other?

Answer (score 4):

You need to add this dependency in the gradle file

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

Comment: I am using Eclips not android studio

Comment: @KomalNikhare then you need to add that library to your project from `..../sdk/extras/android/support/design` to your project.

Comment: I have already added this library into my project all settings have done, but still showing an error..

Comment: Solve these error by changing AppCompact theme... thank you

@NigamPatro Iam working in INDIA

Answer (score 0):

Definitelly, you need to add the dependency inside the `build.gradle` file located inside `/app`

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.1' //change compile to implementation
    ...
    }
}
```

but if you are still using Eclipse probably will have some problems using the support library, i recommend to start using Android Studio.

> **[The Eclipse ADT plugin is no longer supported per our announcement.](https://developer.android.com/studio/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html)**
>   Android Studio is now the official IDE for Android, so you should
>   migrate your projects to Android Studio as soon as possible. For more
>   information on transitioning to Android Studio, see Migrate to Android
>   Studio from Eclipse.